# How can I check new contact added in phone

Tags: react-native, react-native-contacts

I'm use react-native and react-native-contacts, so, I need the total list of contacts to persist that. Then, when the user open again the app I need to check contacts added for save it again only this newers.

Exist any method for that?

Comment: If you are already saving the contacts, can't you just find contacts returned from `react-native-contacts` that are not in your database?

Comment: Of course I can. But I dont want iterate the all list, I just need the new contact register.

Comment: There is no default functionality for this, however, iterating your list should not be very intensive. Especially if you are using something like sqlite

Answer (score 0):

No method for this. You can iterate as @CampbellMG said in the application. If you want this feature please open an issue in the tracker.